# Using consecutive matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm creating a function to use multiple matrices in an analysis studio.

The matrices are given with the same name with a date reference in the name (month to month and year to year: nov-1956 is `matrix5611`, dec-1956 is `matrix5612`, jan-1957 is `matrix5712`, and so on until the end of 1999.

For each one there should be a comparison between the mean value of each month/year (depending of what area of study are you focused on).

I'm trying to use some loops to vary the name of the input matrix instead of write manually date by date, but a function that helped would be useful.

Any idea or useful function?

Comment: `S = load('mydata.mat');` is very useful, you can then do structure access using dynamic field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your data in different matrices, you can use `eval` to store the means to some matrix, in this example `MeanMatrix`, in which Y dimension is year and X dimension is month:

Edit: It's not running number from 5611 but yymm...

Edit: It seems that matrices don't begin from January 1956 but from November 1956.

```
% add here missing months matrix index strings.

MissingMatricesCellArray = {'5601', '5602', '5603', '5604', '5605', '5606', '5607', '5608', '5609', '5610'};

% MissingmatricesCellArray = {};

for Year = 56:99
    for Month = 1:12
        NumString = sprintf('%02d%02d', Year, Month);

        % calculate and store means only for matrices that are not missing.
        if ~(ismember (cellstr(NumString), MissingMatricesCellArray))
            MeanMatrix(Year,Month) = mean(mean(eval ([ 'matrix', NumString ])));
        end
     end
end
```

Then you can compare the means of months and years the way you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Both answer have plenty meaning right now

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use cell array's for this rather than `eval`.

```
for y = 56:99 % for each year 
    for m = 1:12 % for each month    
      ind = createYearMonthInd(y,m);
      matrix{ind} = ...  % whatever you want here (note the curly braces)
   end 
end 


function ind = createYearMonthInd(y,m)
     ind = y * 100 + m;
```

Comment: I understood that OP has received the original data as separate matrices named `matrix5611`, `matrix5612`, `matrix5701` and so on and so use of any more convenient form of storing of data (such as a cell array or one matrix for all data) would require first conversion from separate matrices, for which I think you need to use `eval` or, alternatively, generate and run a custom function.

Comment: Agreed, if OP is so constrained, then he is. I simply wanted to make him aware of this feature.